# SSRS Report Manager Report names

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Is it possible to have SSRS's Report Manager display a report name that is not the .RDL file name?

I.E. I have a Report .RDL named "MyReportAboutSomeImportantStuff.RDL" but I want the Report Manager to display this user friendly as "My Report About Some Important Stuff."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. After deploying to the reportserver, you can browse to the report through Report Manager and use the "Properties" tab to manually change the displayed name of the report - e.g. inserting the spaces.

If you get sick of doing this by hand (and you will), it's also possible to script this and several other post-deployment operations using rs.exe. See [TechNET: Scripting Deployment and Administrative Tasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972248.aspx)

Comment: Handy, but it's really annoying how this changes the physical name on the server, rather than just functioning as a 'display name'. So linked reports would have to be updated, users' bookmarks, etc. Having both a 'file' and displayed name would be too easy, I guess. Thanks, MS ;)